# Where is this Pytorch NN version of a Keras example wrong?

Tags: neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

I want to write a network inverting the Radon transform. I found an example in Keras [here](https://github.com/YIZHE12/ML_DeepCT/blob/master/Image_reconstruction/Deep_learning/train.py). The network is given by:

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,img_size,no_angles)))# FC 1 , output shape (_,img_size*no_angles)
model.add(Dense(img_size*no_angles))# FC 2 , output shape (_,img_size*no_angles*2)    
model.add(Activation('tanh'))

model.add(Dense(int(img_size*img_size)))# FC 3 , output shape (_,img_size*img_size*4)      
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5, seed = 1))
model.add(Reshape((1,int(img_size),int(img_size)) ) )    

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation = 'elu', data_format="channels_first", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.0001))) # C1
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation = 'elu', data_format="channels_first" )) # C2
#model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,1)))      
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='elu', data_format="channels_first" ) ) # C3

rms = RMSprop(lr=0.00002, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rms, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
```

with summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8640)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 8640)              74658240  
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 8640)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              8848384   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 1, 32, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 32, 32)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 32, 32)         9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 1, 32, 1)          289       
=================================================================
Total params: 83,525,409
Trainable params: 83,525,409
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now I tried to convert this Network to Pytorch:

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.fc1     = nn.Linear(48*180, 48*180, dtype=float)
    self.fc2     = nn.Linear(48*180, 32*32, dtype=float)
    self.drop    = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    self.conv1   = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.convT1  = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.tanh    = nn.Tanh()
    
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.tanh(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = self.tanh(x)
    x = self.drop(x)
    x = x.view(-1, 32, 32)
    x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 1)
    x = F.elu(self.conv1(x))
    x = F.elu(self.conv1(x))
    x = F.elu(self.convT1(x))
    return x

model = ConvNet().to(device)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, alpha=0.9)
```

With summary:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
           Flatten-1                 [-1, 8640]               0
            Linear-2                 [-1, 8640]      74,658,240
              Tanh-3                 [-1, 8640]               0
            Linear-4                 [-1, 1024]       8,848,384
              Tanh-5                 [-1, 1024]               0
           Dropout-6                 [-1, 1024]               0
            Conv2d-7            [-1, 1, 32, 32]              10
            Conv2d-8            [-1, 1, 32, 32]              10
   ConvTranspose2d-9            [-1, 1, 32, 32]              10
================================================================
Total params: 83,506,654
Trainable params: 83,506,654
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.03
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.24
Params size (MB): 318.55
Estimated Total Size (MB): 318.83
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

As input I assumed to be given data (the sinogram) of size 48x180 and that the corresponding image is of size 32x32. Judging from the number of parameters in terms of the 2D convolutions, there seems to be something wrong with my setup but I can't figure out what.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Two things: (1) you are using the incorrect number of filters for your convolutional layers (you are using 1 instead of 32 in the keras example) and (2) you are reusing one convolutional layer for two operations instead of having two separate convolutional layers (i.e. sharing the parameters instead of having two separate sets of parameters).

Comment: @Oxbowerce thanks! I get the second reference and added an extra conv-layer. But where do I set the number of filters for Pytorch Conv2D? Is filter just a different word for in/out_channels?

Comment: Setting the number of filters of a convolutional layer in pytorch can be done by changing the value for `out_channels` to the number of filters you want, see also [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032042/9435355).

Comment: @Oxbowerce thanks again for the comment. I tried to adapt the model accordingly, but I can't make it work. In order to have 9248 parameters for the first Conv2d layer in the Pytorch model, I think i would need nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1) right? But the fully connected layer and reshaping only gives me one input channel so I end up with nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, padding=1) and 320 parameters. Am I missing something obvious?